# Bootstrap Date Time Picker not selecting current time when the today button is hit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap Date Time Picker not selecting current time when the today button is hit?

http://jsfiddle.net/9osk7w2j/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" placeholder="datetimepicker" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    locale: 'en-au',
    showTodayButton: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What "Matthew Malone" told in his answer is correct. DateTimepicker is working fine in bootstrap-datetimepicker v3.But not working properly in v4.

So you have two choices.

1.Use bootstrap-datetimepicker v3 - which will work straight away.

2.With the small tweak in your code you can get the current date time with bootstrap-datetimepicker v4.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
   useCurrent: false
   }).on('dp.show', function() {
   if($(this).data("DateTimePicker").date() === null)
     $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(moment());
   });
});
```

You can check https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1311 for the issue with v4.

I tested both the ways it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work. All that does is use 12h time and instead of 00:00 is selects 12:00

Comment: I updated my answer.There are 2 choices for you.You can use any one of those depends on your interest.Both are working fine.

Comment: Note, I do not think your solution works with the "showTodayButton: true" flag

Answer (score 0):

Found that the previous version 4.15.35 works and version 4.17.37 does not!

http://jsfiddle.net/zf5h4mms/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.15.35/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 4.17.49 does not work. 4.15.35 does not work